# How can I bind a button to a viewmodel command from within a data template that's in Page.Resources?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-app-sdk

In my app using the Windows App SDK, I'm trying to get a button-tapped event to trigger a command in my viewmodel. I have gotten this to work when the data template is between the  and  on the page, but it won't work when the data template is in Page.Resources. I have to place some data templates in Page.Resources because I need to have multiple data templates in the TreeView and use a DataTemplateSelector to select the correct one based on the type of the item. I've gotten the template selection working, but I just can't get the button binding to work. It looks like the ElementName binding can't find the page name. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="treeViewSFTemplate" x:DataType="models:SF">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OwnedSFEs}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SFName}"/>
                    <Button Content="+">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=sfSettingsPage, Path=ViewModel.AddNewSubfactorCommand}"/>
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="-"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>

       
        <DataTemplate x:Key="treeViewSFETemplate" x:DataType="models:SFE">
        <TreeViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SFEName}"/>
                <Button Content="+">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=thisPage, Path=ViewModel.DeleteSFECommand}"/>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
                <Button Content="-"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And then in the in the page code below:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" 
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SFList}" 
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource treeViewDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that you wrapped a `TreeViewItem` in
the DataTemplate. It will cause that `TreeViewItem` contains sub-TreeViewItem in the Visual Tree and you could not access correct DataContext with element name in your button. Please remove `TreeViewItem` from your code.

Like:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="treeViewSFETemplate" x:DataType="models:SFE">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SFEName}"/>
            <Button Content="+">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=thisPage, Path=ViewModel.DeleteSFECommand}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="-"/>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I remove <TreeViewItem> from the date template for the second level of my list (treeViewSFETemplate), the buttons to work on that level do work. But if remove it from the other level, the first level list item will no longer expand.

Comment: @Matt As I mentioned, If you must add a TreeViewItem inside the DataTemplate, the DataContext will be the `SFE model`. The button will be limited to the the `SFE model` and it can't access other DataContext. So you will have to put the command into the corresponed `SFE model`.

Comment: I finally just broke from MVVM and used a "tapped" event on the button within the data template. The event triggers a method on the view's code behind. That method in turn calls the method I needed to reach on the view model. Thanks all for the responses.

Comment: @Matt Glad to hear that you've found your way! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the view model `MyViewModel` for the page is bound to the `DataContext` property of the page and `MyItemViewModel` is the datatype of the item in a collection. The `CommandParameter` binding binds the view model of the item:

```
<Page
 ...
 x:Name="MyPage"
 ...
  <Page.Resources>
  ...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" x:DataType="vm:MyItemViewModel>
    ...
      <Button
      ...
        Command="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        ...
```

Changes to the value of the property `DataContext` can be verified by adding an eventhandler after `InitializeComponent()` in the page constructor:

```
public MyPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ...
  DataContextChanged += MyPage_DataContextChanged;
  ...
}

void MyPage_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
{
  if (DataContext is MyViewModel vm)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the data context, but binding doesn't seem to be able to find it either.

Comment: Try debugging the SelectTemplateCore override in the DataTemplateSelector.